# mysql insert into csv file not working in python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have tried many times and searched all over the internet and this is still not working for me.
I am trying to read from a csv file and insert data into a database with python.
This is my code, and I don't understand why it's not working

```
import mysql.connector
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open(r'files\files1.csv') as csv_file:
    csvfile = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    allvalues=[]
    for row in csvfile:
        value = (row[0],row[1],row[2])
        allvalues.append(value)

print(allvalues)

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'ip',
    user = 'user',
    passwd = 'pass',
    database = 'db',
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)

cursor = db.cursor()

query = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (%s , %s , %s)"

cursor.execute(query, allvalues)

db.commit()
```

this gives the following error:

```
   result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type tuple cannot be converted
```

I also want to mentions that I have tried many other things to insert into the table not only the method above, and everytime I get a different error.

Can someone please tell me how do I do it? I would really appreciate it

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `cursor.executemany(query, allvalues)`

If you have multiple elements which are saved in a list or tuple then use,

`cursor.executemany(query, list)` or `cursor.executemany(query, tuple)`

Or you can use for loop

```
for value in allvalues:
    cursor.execute(query, value)
```